# How to upload mysql database to phpfog?

Tags: ruby, hosting, cloud, cloud-hosting, phpfog

I have created an and I want to upload that on phpfog but I am getting trouble while uploading my database here on the first step, I have `win 7 x64` , I downloaded and installed `command prompt with ruby`, while creating a tunnel :

```
`C:\wamp\www\myapp>af tunnel
[WARNING] DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
To use `af tunnel', you must first install Caldecott:

        gem install caldecott

Note that you'll need a C compiler. If you're on OS X, Xcode
will provide one. If you're on Windows, try DevKit.

This manual step will be removed in the future.

Error: Caldecott is not installed.`
```

But while installing caldecott -

```
`C:\wamp\www\myapp>gem install caldecott
Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing caldecott:
        The 'eventmachine' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'`
```

can anybody help me to get it done ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the DevKit first.
You have more information here:

http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

and: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit